# How to loop over a GET request and do a POST every key found

Tags: postman, jira

Just started playing around withPostman a week ago to make life easier.

**Situation :**
I have a get request which returns x amount of key (Jira userstories)

**What do i want to achieve :**
I want to create subtask for each of the keys i get back from the GET request with Postman

The POST part on how to create the subtask is already done. My issue is specifically looping through the GET request list to create it for every story.

Any help would be much appreciated

My postman GET request :

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 8,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "59332",
        "self": "xxx",
        **"key": "GRIP-502"**
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "58465",
        "self": "xx",
        "key": "GRIP-429"
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "56409",
        "self": "xxxx",
        **"key": "GRIP-338"**
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "55191",
        "self": "xxx",
        "key": "GRIP-246"
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "55180",
        "self": "xx",
        **"key": "GRIP-244"**
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "52783",
        "self": "xx",
        "key": "GRIP-104"
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "51641",
        "self": "xxx",
        "key": "GRIP-69"
    },
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "51473",
        "self": "xx",
        "key": "GRIP-48"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first request where you get the information store the issues into a variable:

```
pm.environment.set("issues",pm.response.json().issues)
```

In the pre-request section of the POSt request you want to send use :

```
  let array = pm.environment.get("issues")
  let issue = array.pop()
   
  pm.environment.set("issues",array)
  pm.environment.set("id",issue.id) // or key what ever you want
  array.length!==0?postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName):null
```

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS. just logged in and saw message popup!! Ill try it and let you know the results.

Comment: For the GET request i added the first line of code into "Tests". Result was creation of  env variable [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: ya just retrieve it and print it , console.log(pm.environment.get("issues")) it will resolve it as an array correctly .

Comment: it shows object object because its stored as object not string

Comment: For the GET request i added the first line of code under "Tests". Result was creation of  env variable [object Object],[object Object]. In de Post i added the second line of code in pre-request script. De response for the get request gets me 2 records (active sprint). But only for the first story subtask are created if i run it. Please advise. (I hit enter to fast). And went into the retro.

Comment: @JurgenWoen https://www.getpostman.com/collections/e5df08332de248a3f254 import this collection, goto import>link and paste. then run it using collection runner

Comment: you can see the second reqeust getting repeated as many times as number of issue items with id changing dynamically

Comment: Sprint change today. I import it and it runs fine. But i am totally lost. You do a post and then a get . I had it the other way around. You also put pm.environment.set("issues",pm.response.json().issues) in de POST and the other part in de GET. But it works fine when i run it. Ill play around with it some more. Since i have some time now.

Comment: its just an example to show that you are itearting and sending the second request dynamically with different values. You can change to get , query parameter to json reqeust body etc. Use the apporach as baseline :) if it helped please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: Hello PHide, it worked flawlessly, ty so much. One more question if i may. I only want to do the put for records where subtasks: [0]. I know i have to do something with array ===0 but cant get it quit to work. Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: array[0]  will give you that particular  element

Comment: note that we are using array.pop() so once your post request completes your array will be empty  as pop will remove the element and update the source array. If you want to  the array again then in first reqeust create two varaibles , one for looping over and one for retreiving it

Comment: So my array looks something like  
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
3: {…}
4: {…}
5: {…}
6: {…}
7: {…} 
3: {…}
expand: "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields"
id: "55191"
self: "https://jira.xx"
key: "GRIP-246"
fields: {…}
Under field we have "subtask" : [0]
I Only want to select those records where subtask [0] and do the put.
Thank you so much for the help, if you have a by me a coffee link pm me it :)

Comment: Thats sweet :D Not as of now but you could buy someone who really need one,  behalf of me share the love

Answer (score 0):

You could write a javascript function to iterate and process each issue in your response. For example:

```js
function createSubTask(issueId) {
    console.log(`POST Subtask: ${issueId}`);
}

for (let subtask of response.issues) {
 createSubTask(subtask.id)
}
```

You can find more help [here](https://community.postman.com/t/loop-to-test-response-body/14955)

Comment: Hi Raviadhikari, Can you be a bit more specific. Do i need to add the above code under testscript for the request ? And how does it iterate over all the avaliable keys from the request ?

Comment: You're expected to use Postman for testing. Hence, you can execute a custom test script in `Tests` section as `pm.test('TestCase0', pm.expect(...))`. However, if your requirement is running an automation script and more complicated work, you can go for Python, Javascript, etc.